# How to change the adaptive card button property?

Tags: css, node.js, direct-line-botframework, adaptive-cards

Developing a webapp bot using Microsoft bot framework and using Nodejs sdk v3. Trying to implement a feedback functionality. Using buttons and adding submit action to it in the adaptive cards.

When clicked on the button, able to capture the value of that button. But also want to change the color of the button after clicking. Is there any way to do it, tried using CSS but no luck.

```
{
    "type": "ColumnSet",
    "columns": [
    {
        "type": "Column",
        "width": "Auto",
        "items": [
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "★"
        }
        ],
        "selectAction": {
            "type": "Action.Submit",
            "title": "1",
            "data": {
                "feedback": "1"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Column",
        "width": "Auto",
        "items": [
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "★"
        }
        ],
        "selectAction": {
            "type": "Action.Submit",
            "title": "2",
            "data": {
                "feedback": "2"
            }
        }
    }                 
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you attach some of your code to this question? generally speaking, you can utilize the #style:focus or #style:active flags in CSS. For more assistance, please share your code here.

Comment: @YoavAbadi  I have tried  the active and focus you mentioned but i wantto change the button color after clicking the button and that color change should be visible and and it should persist also

Comment: Did you tried to change the button with an "onclick" event listener? in the event's callback to change the button's color? element.style.background-color = "black"? Please attach your code.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @YoavAbadi please refer the code

Comment: @vaatsalya Please try my suggestion in the above